# Updating entities with EF (Delete, Add, Update) with one method

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a WCF service, which has a method for updating a EF entity. The update method works just fine but looks ugly. I think due to some EF design I have to manually set the change tracker state to `Modified` or `Deleted` or `Added`. The update method in the server side looks like this:

```
public Event UpdateEvent(Guid sessionID, Event _event)
{
    Session session = IFSHelperClass.CheckSession(sessionID);

    try
    {
         using (IFSDB ifsdb = new IFSDB())
         {
             ifsdb.Events.Attach(_event);
             ifsdb.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(_event, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);

             // mark the modified and added items
             // for the navigation property 'EventPersons'
             foreach (var p in _event.EventPersons)
             {
                if (p.ChangeTracker.State == IFSEntities.ObjectState.Added)
                    ifsdb.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(p, System.Data.EntityState.Added);

                 if (p.ChangeTracker.State == IFSEntities.ObjectState.Modified)
                    ifsdb.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(p, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
             }

             // since the deleted items will not be available in the
             // navigation property, delete them manually from the
             // ChangeTracker object.
             if (_event.ChangeTracker.ObjectsRemovedFromCollectionProperties.Count > 0)
             {
                 var personsToDelete = _event.ChangeTracker.ObjectsRemovedFromCollectionProperties.Where(t => t.Key == "EventPersons").Select(t => t.Value)
                     .FirstOrDefault()
                     .ToList();

                foreach (EventPerson p in personsToDelete)
                {
                  ifsdb.EventPersons.Attach(p);
                  ifsdb.EventPersons.DeleteObject(p);
                }
            }

            // save all changes and accept them
            ifsdb.SaveChanges();
            _event.AcceptChanges();
            foreach (var p in _event.EventPersons)
                p.AcceptChanges();

            return _event;
          }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          Logger.LogError("UpdateEvent()", ex.Message, ex.ToString(), session.User.UserID);
          throw ex;
      }
 }
```

As you can see, II iterate through the navigation property items to check for updates or deletes and mark them manually.

Is this the way? or am I doing something ugly here?

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't expose entities in WCF service. Every change in entity will cause WCF webservice change and incompatibility for existing consumers. I would create decicated data transfer objects for WCF webservice and use library like Automapper to handle property mapping.

EF entities often contain various properties (example: creation date, creator info), that shouldn't be modified, but when you expose whole entities, you allow this, which in future may cause security issues.

Small example (without Automapper):

```
public class EventDTO 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

In webservice class:

```
public Event UpdateEvent(Guid sessionID, EventDTO eventDTO)
{
    using (IFSDB ifsdb = new IFSDB())
    {
        var event = ifsdb.Events.First(item => item.Id == eventDTO.Id);
        event.EventDate = eventDTO.EventDate;
        event.Title = eventDTO.Title;
        ifsdb.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```